# What is the role of ASP when you make C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm asking what is the purpose of ASP when you develop on C#

Thanks

Comment: ASP.net is the framework/platform I would say. It gives you libraries (classes, objects, states, events, ...) you don't have in a windows forms app. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info

Comment: ASP or ASP.NET? Classic ASP has nothing to do with C#, but what do you mean?

Comment: * C# is the programming language.
* ASP.NET is web framework (base functionality).
* ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC are additional frameworks for creating web pages. You use C# syntax to code against .NET common libraries and ASP.NET libraries.

Answer (score 1):

"ASP.NET is a server-side Web application framework designed for Web development to produce dynamic Web pages. It was developed by Microsoft to allow programmers to build dynamic web sites, web applications and web services."

The above brief is from Wikipedia describing what ASP.NET is. However if you are asking about classic ASP, then that is now very rarely used mainly for it's security weaknesses and lack of features.

**C#** is a Microsoft .Net language that can be used for either desktop applications which can consume web services but are run on desktops or stand alone computers. **C# translates into local machines code and hence runs locally**

**ASP.NET** as the above description mentions is a web application framework that uses the programming capabilities of **C#** in a web development environment. **In ASP.NET, the C# bits of code is processed on the server side into plain HTML/XHTML  and transferred to the client browser for display. C# provides the tools to do tasks that HTML and any client side scripting language like JavaScript can not do.**

While C# is mostly the language of choice for developers, ASP.NET can use any CLR (Common Language Runtime) programming language like VB.Net, F#, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ASP is for generating web pages and can be used by itself or usually with a .Net language behind to do clever stuff. C# might be used with ASP .Net but might also be used by itself in a Windows or other standalone app.
ASP includes server tags which can be controlled from code to dynamically change the content of the web pages. It looks a bit like HTML but the tag names are different.
Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Package details</asp:Label>
```